# Volley to Room SQLite with existing Primary keys

Tags: android, sqlite, android-volley, android-room

I have a REST API, which is providing the JSON as follows

```
{  
   "id":3,
   "package":"premimum",
   "company_id":6
}
```

Now I want to fetch the data from the the API and then add that data to the SQLite for offline use. So how I can insert the `id`'s value in the SQLite table `packages` as primary key? or should I use the other way? or something else you can suggest me?

Comment: @Shawn as you can see in the json I posted, have the `id` which is primary key, so when adding data i the SQLite, should I create the new primary key for local? if not then how I can use the above `id` as the primary key for local?

Comment: I have record already in the remote server, now I fetched that record and now I want to insert that record in the SQLite for offline use. So should I create the new primary id in SQLite? because I already have `id` column in the remote server as primary key. I mean the primary key on the remote server and the primary key in the SQLite local database should be same? or should I keep them different? what is best approach?

Comment: @Shawn let suppose you are fetching data from the API and insert that data to the SQLite, will your primary keys will be sync also? as in my question the package `premium` have the primary key value `3` now when I insert that data in the SQLite should the primary key `id` will be same `3` for the package `premium` in the offline record? What should I do? keep primary key values also same?